# Convergente of sum of divisors sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma$ the application that transforms $n$ into the sum of its divisors (ex : $\sigma\left(6\right)=12$)\
I've proved that
$$
n+1 \leq \sigma\left(n\right) \leq n+n\ln\left(n\right)
$$
I know that
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sigma\left(k\right)}{n^2} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}\frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$
I just want to show that this sequence converges (because I guess the limit value $\pi^2/12$ is not that easy to neatly get with elementary math). I think that this sequence decreases, and it would be sufficient for me to show it but I havent been successful in proving it.

Any hint ?

Comment: Hardy and Wright have your sum as Theorem 324, page 266 in the fifth edition. There is a sixth edition, modest changes by Heath-Brown and J. H. Silverman. Alright, just before we see Theorem 323 credited to Gronwall, $$  \limsup \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n} = e^\gamma $$ Much later, G. Robin gave very precise information about Gronwall's ratio

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious to me that $\frac{\sum_{k\le n}\sigma(k)}{n^2}$ may be decreasing. It is immediate that it converges from

$$\sum_{k\le n}\sigma(k)=\sum_{k\le n}\sum_{dm=k}d=\sum_{dm\le n} d=\sum_{m\le n} \frac{\lfloor n/m\rfloor (\lfloor n/m\rfloor+1)}{2}= n^2 \sum_{m\le n} \frac{1}{2m^2}+O(\sum_{m\le n} n/m)$$